# Is Dabiq town really prophesized in Islamic Escatology for the end time war?

Tags: source-identification, war, end-times

This critical article on ISIS suggests that some Muslims believe that a final Armageddon war will happen in Dabiq, currently conquered by ISIS. So is this really true, and if yes what are the evidences in Islam?

> The Islamic State awaits the army of “Rome,” whose defeat at Dabiq, Syria, will initiate the countdown to the apocalypse.

http://www.theatlantic.com/features/archive/2015/02/what-isis-really-wants/384980/

Answer (score 1):

There is one hadith in Sahih Muslim(collection of prophet's saying) which mention about dabiq. Given below is that hadith.

> The Last Hour would not come until the Romans would land at al-A'maq
>   or in Dabiq. An army consisting of the best (soldiers) of the people
>   of the earth at that time will come from Medina (to counteract them).
>   When they will arrange themselves in ranks, the Romans would say: Do
>   not stand between us and those (Muslims) who took prisoners from
>   amongst us. Let us fight with them; and the Muslims would say: Nay, by
>   Allah, we would never get aside from you and from our brethren that
>   you may fight them. They will then fight and a third (part) of the
>   army would run away, whom Allah will never forgive. A third (part of
>   the army) which would be constituted of excellent martyrs in Allah's
>   eye, would be killed and the third who would never be put to trial
>   would win and they would be conquerors of Constantinople. And as they
>   would be busy in distributing the spoils of war (amongst themselves)
>   after hanging their swords by the olive trees, the Satan would cry:
>   The Dajjal has taken your place among your family. They would then
>   come out, but it would be of no avail. And when they would come to
>   Syria, he would come out while they would be still preparing
>   themselves for battle drawing up the ranks. Certainly, the time of
>   prayer shall come and then Jesus (peace be upon him) son of Mary would
>   descend and would lead them in prayer. When the enemy of Allah would
>   see him, it would (disappear) just as the salt dissolves itself in
>   water and if he (Jesus) were not to confront them at all, even then it
>   would dissolve completely, but Allah would kill them by his hand and
>   he would show them their blood on his lance (the lance of Jesus
>   Christ). http://sunnah.com/muslim/54/44

I do not know more about this hadith, like authenticity, what it mean etc.

Comment: I'm upvoting your for finding the hadith, but it's not normally sufficient to provide hadith without proper explanation....

Comment: This hadith is also unauthentic

Answer (score 0):

Considering this town is closer to Turkey than Saudi Arabia, I doubt it was a statement the prophet actually made. It sounds like a late fabrication during the Ummayad/Byzantine wars. Rome for the Arabs was Constantinople, Turkey at that time, so it makes sense geographically (not Rome in Italy).

Comment: And swords and lances. This must have happened long ago.

Comment: Suhayl bin Abi Salih, the 4th transmitter in the chain, was considered da'if (weak) by Daraqutni, Nasa'i said his hadith are matruk (abandoned) and Yahya bin Sa'id al-Qattan said he mixes things or alters.